# Old sci-fi film with submarine like Vehicle

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I saw these movie before some 15 years ago and don't remember much of anything. I only have glimpse of it, of what I remember is as follows.

- Movie is set up in submarine like vehicle, extremely huge in size. I remember A big glass dome and in that hall everything is made of whole gold.
- The protagonist was a pirate or a thief.
- In the climax due to some accident the ship or submarine sinks but the protagonist survives and he takes out the golden spoon which he stole earlier and throws it back in water.

Please help me identify this move. was my first scifi movie I saw it as a kid.

Comment: This sounds a lot like 20,000 leagues under the sea from 1954: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1954_film)

Comment: ...or one of the [adaptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptations_of_Twenty_Thousand_Leagues_Under_the_Sea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your description and from wikipedia, I think the movie is

[**Captain Nemo and the Underwater City**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Nemo_and_the_Underwater_City)

It also states the following for climax

> The film closes as Nautilus turns towards Templemir. On the surface, a
>   small schooner is seen picking up two men in mid-ocean, far from
>   either land or any sign of wreckage. Frazer and Swallow Bath, huddled
>   in blankets, are made welcome aboard, and as the schooner prepares to
>   set sail, **Frazer finds his companion has concealed a gold ladle under
>   his coat. The two exchange rueful smiles, and Frazer tosses it lightly
>   into the sea.**

Comment: Seems like the closest match so far. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be "[Latitude Zero](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064470/)"? The film is largely set inside a giant submarine and there is gold aplenty on costumes, set-dressing and backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Richard's suggestion, the description also roughly fits the 1954 film, *20,000 Leagues Under the Sea*. (I think somebody posted the Wikipedia link in the comments, but just in case, you can find the Wikipedia description [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1954_film))) I remember watching it as a kid, so it's definitely at least somewhat kid-friendly, and I'm pretty sure the - super fancy - submarine (aka "monster," aka "submerging boat") does get wrecked at the end and the main characters get stranded.
Edit - Here's the trailer, if it's any help: